# Catching general exception - powershell

Tags: exception, powershell

Trying to catch general exception from $Pingy = Get-WmiObject Win32_PingStatus -f "Address='$Fip'" tried already doing catch [Exception], catch[System.Exception] and just catch. Using powershell Version 2.

the question is how to catch that general exception for Get-WmiObject. The code later checks for pingSuccess true or false to determine how to proceed. Right now its always setting pingSuccess to true, which I don't want if the exception is thrown.

```
function Ping
{   
    param($Fip)
    try
    {
    $Pingy = Get-WmiObject Win32_PingStatus -f "Address='$Fip'"  

    return New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        pingSuccess=$true
        ex=$null
        code=$Pingy.statuscode
        }
    }
    catch [System.Exception]
    {
    return New-Object PSObject -property @{
        ex=$_.Exception
        pingSuccess=$false
        }
#   write-host $exc.gettype()
#   write-host $exc.message
#   write-host $exc.innerException
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi - Can you clarify what your question/problem is?

Comment: `get-help about_return`.. the catch will never execute if you always exit the function in the try

Answer (score 0):

It looks like even

```
Win32_PingStatus -f "Address='somenonsehere'"
```

does not cause an error. So you would not get anything that way but if your purpose is to detect whether a computer is pingable or not, maybe you could change your script a bit to do just that.
For example:

```
function Ping
{   
    param($Fip)
    $pingStatus=$false                        
    if ((Get-WmiObject Win32_PingStatus -f "Address='$Fip'").StatusCode -eq 0)   {
            $pingStatus=$true
            #$code=0 ## if you want the code, but you already know that.                        

    } 
         New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            pingSuccess=$pingStatus
          #  code=0
}
```

}